# Failure installing SQL Server 2008 R2 Express X64

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, sql-server-2008-r2, installation

I am having a serious problem installing this (from web platform installer and from the downloaded installer). I have a laptop with win7 x64 enterprise on it.

I have read the forums and tried all the solutions I have found, from permissions, .NET framework to copying the setup files etc. These did help move the install on but in the end it always fails for the database. I have tried following MS advice on trying to read the log files to see where it fails which is why I looked at some of the solutions but the fixes didn't work. What makes it worse is the solutions for retrying the install (removal of things from the registry) has made things worse on the laptop as other stings stop working every time I remove the SQL keys.

I was hoping someone here could look over the logs to see if they could give me a better indication of whats wrong. Problem is I can't see a way of attaching a zip file here

Comment: Please, be kind and post those logs you have here, so we can see what's the problem about.

Comment: We definitely need more information in order to answer.  Posting the relevant log entries will be a big help.  Are you getting errors when it fails?  What exactly happens when it fails?

Comment: Do you just want them as a text file dump, if so which ones do you need to start with. i have zipped them all up but i cant see any way of uploading the zip file.

Comment: Solved this in the end by creating a local admin and giving every permission i could. went on like a dream, it even upgraded to full version of SQl without a hitch.